# AWS Load Balancer: 503 (Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity)

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I setup a load balancer that is forwarding https (443) to https (443) on a simple EC2 nano with AMI Linux using a SSL cert from AWS. After some hours/days by opening the website over https I get a:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity)
```

It is redirecting all requests on port 80 to 443 using the .htaccess file.

That is really really annoying. What is wrong in my configuration?

Comment: Can you paste the output of "df -h" on your EC2 instance?

Comment: Have you reviewed the logs of your application?  Reviewed the logs from ELB?  Checked the CPU credit balance on your nano?  There's probably not a fundamental thing "wrong" with your configuration, but a t2.nano is a very tiny machine -- which is great when well-matched to the workload, but easily overwhelmed when not.

Answer (score 4):

For me it happen for another reason - i had no response for root path, e.g. `www.myenv.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`, i did had for other path (`/someapi/x`). But apparently the Load Balancer check the root response and if it's not `200` it will return this `503`, which is a bit confusing..

Edit:
Another option is to change the `Application Health Check` path in the configurations

Comment: Perfect. This was my issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

OK. The t2.nano just did not have enough power to run that wordpress site. Now I scaled up and it works without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely misconfigured your health-check (or your health-check returns an error because your (proxy-) server is not working correctly). Check your ELB logs.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I misconfigured the http servers on my EC2 instances. I had a bad line on my nginx.conf file, started nginx through Windows Task Scheduler, but did not check to see that it was actually running. Task scheduler showed that it was, but it wasn't. So all my EC2 instances were failing health checks.